# how to query a list of objects containing multiple lists in them?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of patients.
each patient has several lists:

```
public class Patient
{
    private List<DateTime> serverTimeStamps;
    protected List<int> sessionStages;
    protected List<string> revIPage;
    protected List<double> current;
    protected List<int> n_ok;
    protected List<int> n_LE;
}
```

The list of patients is called `ptLsit` and I'm trying to get the lists items where the `serverTimeStamp` is bigger than `_initTimeToAskData` (from all the lists, not just serverTimeStamps).
The best example I can give is

```
ptLsit.Where(x=> x.ServerTimeStamps.Select(ts => ts >= _initTimeToAskData))
```

Comment: it is unclear what is the output you want. Do you want the `Patients` that somewhere in there list have a timeStammp greater than the `_initTimeToAskData` or do you want the actual timestamps as output?

Comment: I want a list of patients and I want their list to contain only data that was inserted in serverTimeStamp bigger than _initTimeToAskData

Comment: This remark is not clear: "from all the lists, not just serverTimeStamps". Other lists do not contain timestamps

Comment: they don't, but there is a correlation. say item 15 in serverTimeStamp is bigger than or equal to _initTimeToAskData, then I want item 15 from all lists

Comment: if all serverTimeStamp are smaller than _initTimeoAskData, I don't want this patient in the output

Comment: @Orensig, for this type of correlation you have I would suggest to reconsider the structure of Patient object. If you can change it of course. If item number 5 in all of these lists is related, then consider a single object to represent this item, rather than "time stamp is serverTimeStamps[5], revision page is revIPage[5], etc". It is no good keeping them in separate lists - one item gets removed, deleted or updated in one of the lists and suddenly you are out of sync. As a side effect your question becomes trivial with new structure

Comment: @Orensig please check my answer

Comment: I'm currently working on a different task as priorities in the company have changed. I will get back to it in a few weeks and will check what the best answer is. Thank you all for the attention.

Comment: @Orensig have you been able to check the answer? Thanks

Comment: Nope, I changed the data structure to datatable in order to save the connection between different patient attributes

Answer (score 0):

Based on this class:

```
public class Patient
{
    public List<DateTime> serverTimeStamps;
    public List<int> sessionStages;
    public List<string> revIPage;
    public List<double> current;
    public List<int> n_ok;
    public List<int> n_LE;
}
```

Try this:

```
var result = ptLsit.Where(p => p.serverTimeStamps.Any(d => d > _initTimeToAskData))
    .Select(p => new Patient{
        serverTimeStamps = p.Where(x => x > DateTime.Now).ToList(),
        // Fill the other properties...
        // ...
        });
```

You will get the list of Patient that contains at least a DateTime bigger than the parameter `_initTimeToAskData` and the result objects will contain the correct dates in the `serverTimeStamps` property